# Large deviations for integrands

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, large-deviations

I am a physicist caught in the following situation:
I have two probability measures $\mathbb{P}_1$ and $\mathbb{P}_2$ and have to deal with the following integral where $X_i$ are random iid:

$$\int_{B} \mathbb{P}_1\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \ge x\right) d\mathbb{P}_2(x).$$

I was able to obtain a large deviation principle for $X$, i.e. I was able to show that

$$\frac{1}{N} \log\left( \mathbb{P}_1\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \ge x\right)\right) = -I(x).$$

Now it is tempting to replace $\mathbb{P}_1\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \ge x\right) $ in the above integral by $e^{-N I(x)}$ and compute 
$$\int_{B} e^{-NI(x)} d\mathbb{P}_2(x).$$

However, I do not know in which sense this now close to the expression I am looking for?

Are there any standard bounds to estimate the error between my approximation and the object I am interested in?

Comment: The function I has to be monotone and the rate on the integral ought to be the smallest x in the support of $P_2$.

Comment: @michael The function $I$ is indeed monotone. What precisely does the second part of your comment mean?

Comment: That if V is the value of your integral  $\frac {log(V)} N \rightarrow -\inf \lbrace I(x) \rbrace$ where the inf is over x in the support of $P_2$.  If $P_2$ is really nice, like uniform on an interval, I think it is  easy to write down, but if it has 0 or no density at the lower limit it is probably tedious.

Comment: On second thought, If $P_2$ is really nasty I don't know how bad it can get.  What do you have in mind for $P_2$?

Comment: I am not quite sure you understood my question. I am interested in comparing the value of $$\int_{B} \mathbb{P}_1\left(\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \ge x\right) d\mathbb{P}_2(x)$$ to the value of
$$\int_{B} e^{-NI(x)} d\mathbb{P}_2(x).$$

Comment: The Bahadur-Rao theorem (google it) gives the probability in question up to an $o(1)$ multiplicative error.; there is a $\sqrt{N}$ multiplicative correction with respect to what you write. This is enough to justify the interchange.

Comment: ... but not enough to claim that the last integral approximates the first one (since there is a multiplicative factor that is very far from going to 1 as $N\to\infty$). Plus, only _sharp_ large deviations, not just the LDP (which is asymptotic anyway, not an equality as wrongly stated in the question), allow the comparison. And they require extra conditions on the law of $X_1$ ...

Comment: Sure, existence of exponential moments in a neighborhood of 0 is more than enough.  I'll record my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the shape of $P_2$ and on the assumptions you put on $X_i$. In what follows I'll assume that $\Lambda(\lambda)=\log E_1 e^{\lambda X_1}$ is finite 
for all $\lambda$. I will also assume that $E_1X_i=0$. Further I will assume that 
$P_2$ is supported on $R$ with density $f$.

Case 1: $B\cap (-\infty,0]>0$. In that case your formula may be false, and the answer is essentially $P_2(B\cap (-\infty,0))$.

Case 2: (which is what I guess you had in mind): $B\cap (-\infty,a)=\emptyset$ for some $a>0$. In that case, use Bahadur-Rao to approximate, for $x\in B$,
$P_1(N^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i>x)\sim C(x)e^{-NI(x)}/\sqrt{N}$, with explicit $C=C(x)$. So the expression you write is correct at the exponential scale but if you meant up to precise asymptotics, you are missing a constant multiple and 
a factor $\sqrt{N}$. The constant $C(x)$ depends on whether the law of $X_1$ is lattice or not. See the original paper of Bahadur-Rao or Theorem 3.7.4 in Dembo-Zeitouni's large deviations book.

One can also deal with other cases ($B$ touching $0$ with density of $P_2$ vanishing there, etc.) but I'll stop here.

Comment: thank you. I wonder where the the first case comes from though. Let us say if $\mathbb{P}_2$ is Gaussian. Then, we are in Case $1$, right? So how does this one come about then?

Comment: Depends what B is. if B charges the negative axis, the probability involving $P_1$ is essentially 1!